Unable to cast COM object of type Outlook in vb.net
In my VB.Net WinForms Application which is upgraded from framework 1.1 to 4.7 (Visual Studio 2022, Framework 4.7), I am using Outlook interope dll to send mails.

These are the dlls that i have added in my project.

And the namespace imported as shows
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Globalization
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
    Imports System

And the interope dll that i copied from below location.

When I give the full namespace, the ambiguous error is gone but another error threw as shown below:
    Unable to cast COM object of type 
   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to 
    interface type 
    'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. 
    This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the 
    COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000- 
    C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Element 
    not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B 
    (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND)).

What is this error ??? How to solve ???
The error is thrown here....
     Dim app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application = New 
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application()

     Dim newMail As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem = 
    CType(app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
    OlItemType.olMailItem), 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem) // error threw here

I tried below 2 ways.
    Dim newMail As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem = DirectCast(app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim newMail As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)

But still threw error

Could you try to change the alias name to be  different than namespace suffix, eg.:  Imports OutlookLib = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook ?

@gis I tried. Its not working. Same error message

Have you tried using the full namespace path to the type?

@Craig Yes. Still same error

The fix is quite simple, use the fully-qualified name such as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application. Also, Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop is probably unnecessary and can be commented out or removed.

@user246821 Question updated. I did like u said. but that error gone. another error threw

Glad you were able to resolve the issue. Unfortunately, a new error, requires a new post. By the way, what I mentioned was the exact same fix that @Craig mentioned.

Do you have Outlook installed? Did you set your program bitness (x64 or x86) to the same bitness as the Outlook installed on your computer?

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71516961/10024425

I have solved the issue.
I commented this line
   'Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application

And added below code
    Dim app As Object
    app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

It worked.

The following may be of interest: Early and Late Binding (Visual Basic)
